# Ports open but still can't access from remote

Tags: ip, port, remote, forwarding, dvr

I have a dvr set up and working on local net and my ports are forwarded. I checked and all ports are open but I can't access it from remote using public IP address.

Also zviewer app for phone wont connect it doesn't say port not open but just keeps checking and from friends computer says cannot access page also.

I've used fresh IP address and still not working also tried firewall already on both computers. Is there any reason I'd be having this problem?

Comment: Did you check ports on a port scanner if you are access over the internet?

Answer (score 1):

I think this link will help you if you are windows user.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/allow-remote-desktop-connections-from-outside-your-home-network